# CakePHP query: where condition with calculated fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have the followwing problem with creating a query in CakePHP 3:

For the Entity Recordings I want to calculate the age as the difference between the year of the two dates "collection date" and "birthdate"

```
$query = $this->Recordings->find()
         ->select(['age' => 'Year(Recordings.collection_date) - Year(Athletes.birthdate)'])
         ->select($this->Recordings)
         ->select($this->Recordings->Athletes);
```

When I try to filter with the following where clause

```
$query = $query->where(['Year(Recordings.collection_date) - Year(Athletes.birthdate) =' => $age]);
```

The SQL Code which is created has the Athletes beeing modified to lowercase.

```
WHERE 
  ( Year(Recordings.collection_date) - year(athletes.birthdate) = '17' )
```

How do I have to write the where clause correctly? I havent found a way to use Identifiers or query functions like

```
$year = $q->func()->year(['Athletes.birthdate' => 'identifier']);
```

to bild the conditions.
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: It might work if you just remove all the spaces around the "-" in your condition. There's surely a way to do it with query functions too.

Comment: Note that subtracting the year part of a date is not accurate, depending on month and day of the two values, the result can be off by 1 year. You should look into date diffing methods provided by your DBMS, for example `TIMESTAMPDIFF` for MySQL.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks for your input. This solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @ndm Thanks for you input. The calculation was correct as the age which is relevant in this context is realy calculated on the year of birth and the current year. (based on the sports rules which apply in my application)